# How to set position of element with text

Tags: html, css

I have problem with positioning. 
My picture [image]

I create starburst and insert text like this: [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/6prhw/1/), but i can't create positioning of element like my picture `right: 0; position: relative`.
Suggest me pls.
Thnx.

Comment: what exact element are you trying to move? and where (to the right edge)?

Comment: I try to move my starburst. Yes to right edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need for your `.starburst5`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Dont forget to delete attribute with `position: relative;` from html-element and css.

Answer (score 0):

Used to position relative and absolute

Define your **parent div**  `position relative` and define your **child**

```
position absolute
```

as like this

```
.parent{
     position:relative;
     padding-right:100px;
 }
.starburst5{
        position: absolute;
        right:0;
        top:20px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6prhw/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

use float for anchor tag and for the text and then give the text width